# How to run unittest as 'normal" Dart app

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dart-editor

I'm trying to write tests before implementation. Everything is OK till i have exception like "no such method". 
Running code in html configuration (useHtmlConfiguration()) i have little informations about exception :/ .

QUESTION: Is it possible to run  selected test "solo_test" in configuration that lets me debug exception like in "normal run"

Comment: Bzik, I'm not sure I understand. If you get a "no such method", you are in fact getting some information about the exception. And to answer you general question (if I have understood it): yes, you can use the debugger in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

What type of Exceptions are you throwing?

If you are throwing a String or an Exception, you will not see any stack traces until this commit gets into the unittest package.

https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/detail?r=30322

Until then, make sure you throw instances (or subclasses) of Error.

For you: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/UnimplementedError.html

Then you will see the stack trace data.

Comment: I'm not throwing any exception. I'm trying to interop with js api (Parse.com). I have errors from  Parse. 

When I run test i see error from Parse (ERROR "TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined") but i don't see stock and i don't know where is the problem.
To see the stock i need to make copy of  code from test and paste it somewhere out of test or group method. It's not elegant so I'm looking for some other way :)

PS I am not a programmer, so it's hard to precisely define the problem